# Why NullPointerException occured in WebView?

Tags: android, webview, nullpointerexception, fragment

I tried every examples by Googling and it doesn't work.
When I run my app in my Sony Tablet S. NullPointerException showed in LogCat and then Force close. :(

Thank you very much.

```
public class Lesson_4 extends Fragment {
WebView myWebView;
WebChromeClient chromeClient;
WebViewClient wvClient;
/**
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,
 *      android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
 */

public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
        final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.lessons4, container, false);

    myWebView = (WebView) (getView().findViewById(R.id.webView));
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(wvClient);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNcNOMiSQ5I");   

    return mLinearLayout;

}
```

}

Comment: Please post the stack trace, and pinpoint in your code where it is occurring (make sure you post that code too if you haven't already)

Comment: Stack trace + point the line number in your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post stack trace and the line number in your code where NPE occurs, but I think it's `myWebView = (WebView) (getView().findViewById(R.id.webView));`. Shouldn't it be `myWebView = (WebView) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.webView);`? Of course this `mLinearLayout` has to contain your `webView`.

You can't use getView() inside onCreateView(), because the view you're trying to get is not yet created. Hence NullPointerException.

Comment: Did this solve the problem??? Because i am still getting NPE from the class where i used this subclass of Fragment. I have a ListView inside a LinearLayout as the root in the Fragment. Can anyone please help out..??